# Codeigniter mod-rewrite in apache, removing index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

So I am quite new to codeigniter and I have been trying to get my head around removing the index.php from my local site, I have managed to make it work for the homepage after looking through other similar questions on SO but none have got it fully working. Whenever I visit another page on my site it displays the wamp page on my screen. Here is my code in codeigniter/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
#  slashes.
# If your page resides at
#  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
# then use
# RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have also put in my apache/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But still no luck, is there something I've missed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following step:
1. Change the config file like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

2.Use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: `.htaccess` vary depending on server. I some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: One note: if version 3 is in issue, there is [no](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L40) 'AUTO' uri protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I have done this and now whenever I load a page other than the homepage I get a 404 error, any thoughts? Do I need to do anything with Apache? I have mod-rewrite active

Comment: Have you set `base_url()` in [config](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L6) file?

Comment: Yes I have, I have it set as http://localhost/codeigniter/ and so if I go to http://localhost/codeigniter/about for example I get the 404 error

Comment: If you have mod-rewrite active then it should work perfect. By the way for base url the following lines of code is best:`$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`

Comment: I still have no luck, I am meant to edit that code to work for my site? Is it my routing? I have  `$route['about'] = 'pages/about';$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

Comment: I have just uploaded to my pickaweb hosting and it works great, so maybe it has something to do with my apache setup

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess works on most servers

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You can uncomment the last 2 lines to force HTTPS.

Also this could also work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]                        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>                        
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Note line 3 of the 2nd .htaccess **RewriteBase /foldername/** use this  **RewriteBase /** if your script can be reached without including a folder name.